# Classic ASP RSS Parser and Wordpress Feed compatibility

Tags: wordpress, asp-classic, rss, xml-parsing

I'll preface this question with the fact I'm a web designer and I'm trying to fudge my way through fixing this classic ASP RSS parser code we use here at work, so any basic insight you might be able to offer would be appreciated.

I've run into a road block with this code. It does parse an RSS feed, but generally only feeds that use Feedburner's SmartFeed compatibility settings. What I need it to do is to be able to parse a plain jane Wordpress feed, which it seemingly struggles to do. My goal here is to add additional compatibility so this code isn't so finicky when it comes to parsing feeds.

When I put a straight WP feed in it kicks up the feed not valid error and returns an error code of -2146697211, which from looking up the code seems to imply the feed can't be located. I tried changing *Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.3.0")* to *Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0")*, but it appears that our server doesn't handle 4.0. While this may be something that could be upgraded, getting dev time around here for this issue is pretty unlikely. So I'm left trying to make it work using the current IIS setup, if possible.

Does anyone have any ideas as to any tweaks that could be made to get this working?  Thanks.

```
       <%
                SUB DisplayRSSFeed(URLToRSS, MaxNumberOfItems) 


                Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                IF fs.FileExists(Server.MapPath(TemplatePath & "rss_template.asp")) THEN
                    Set f=fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(TemplatePath & "rss_template.asp"), 1)
                    itemTemplate = f.ReadAll
                    f.Close
                Set f=Nothing 

                ELSE

                    ' =========== configuration =====================
                    ' Item template.
                    ' {LINK} will be replaced with item link
                    ' {TITLE} will be replaced with item title
                    ' {DESCRIPTION} will be replaced with item description
                    'ItemTemplate = "<tr><td><a target='_blank' href=" & """{LINK}""" & ">{TITLE}</a><BR>{DESCRIPTION}</td></tr>"

                    ItemTemplate = ""
                    ItemTemplate = ItemTemplate & "<div class=""sp_blogPost"">"
                    ItemTemplate = ItemTemplate & "     <h2><a href=""{LINK}"" target=""_blank"">{TITLE}</a></h2>"
                    ItemTemplate = ItemTemplate & "     <h5>Posted on {DATE}</h5>"
                    ItemTemplate = ItemTemplate & "     <p>"
                    ItemTemplate = ItemTemplate & "         {DESCRIPTION}"
                    ItemTemplate = ItemTemplate & "     </p>"
                    ItemTemplate = ItemTemplate & "     <a href=""{LINK}"" target=""_blank"">Continue Reading Article</a>"
                    ItemTemplate = ItemTemplate & "</div>"
                    ItemTemplate = ItemTemplate & "<div class=""sp_blogDivider""></div>"
                    ' ================================================
                END IF 

                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                    xmlHttp.Open "Get", URLToRSS, false
                    IF Err.number <> 0 then
                        Response.Write "The URL is not valid"
                        Exit Sub            
                    END IF        
                    xmlHttp.Send()
                    RSSXML = xmlHttp.ResponseText

                Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.3.0")
                    xmlDOM.async = false
                    xmlDOM.LoadXml(RSSXML)
                    IF Err.number <> 0 then
                        Response.Write "The RSS Data is not valid"
                        Response.Write Err.number
                        Exit Sub            
                    END IF        

                    Set RSSItems = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("item") ' collect all "items" from downloaded RSS        

                    j = -1
                    FOR EACH RSSItem IN RSSItems
                    FOR EACH child IN RSSItem.childNodes
                        Select case lcase(child.nodeName)
                            case "title"
                                RSStitle = child.text
                            case "enclosure"
                                RSSimage = child.getAttribute("url")
                    ''      case "link"
                    ''          RSSlink = child.text
                            case "guid"
                                RSSlink = child.text
                            case "description"
                                RSSdescription = child.text

                                Set re = New RegExp
                                re.Pattern = "<[^>]+>"
                                re.IgnoreCase = true
                                re.Global = true

                                RSSdescription = re.Replace(RSSdescription, "")

                                set re = nothing

                                if len(RSSdescription) > 300 then RSSdescription = mid(RSSdescription, 1, 300) & "..."
                            case "pubdate"
                                RSSdate = child.text
                                RSSdate = split(RSSDate, "T")(0)
                                arrDate = split(RSSDate, "-")
                                if ubound(arrDate) = 2 then
                                    RSSdate = arrDate(1) & "." & arrDate(2) & "." & arrDate(0)
                                else
                                    RSSdate = Replace(RSSdate, "-", ".")
                                end if
                        END SELECT
                        NEXT                                     
                            j = J+1                                     
                            IF J < CInt(MaxNumberOfItems) THEN
                                Itemcontent = ItemTemplate
                                Itemcontent = Replace(Itemcontent,"{DATE}", RSSdate)
                                Itemcontent = Replace(Itemcontent,"{IMAGE}", RSSimage)
                                ItemContent = Replace(ItemContent,"{LINK}",RSSlink)
                                ItemContent = Replace(ItemContent,"{TITLE}",RSSTitle)
                                ItemContent = Replace(ItemContent,"{DESCRIPTION}",RSSDescription)

                                Response.Write ItemContent
                                ItemContent = ""
                            END IF
                        NEXT
                    'Response.Write "</table>"
                    On Error GoTo 0
                END SUB
                %>
```

Comment: Instead of Set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")      try     Set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

Comment: or Set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")

Comment: No luck with that, doesn't seem to change anything or kick up a new error at all.

Comment: instead of Response.Write Err.number
try Response.Write Err.Description and see what the error says. can you also post a feed thatdoes not work ?

Comment: It spits out "The system cannot locate the resource specified." If I don't have the error handlers in there it just times out when it hits that line, so for some reason it can't locate it, even though it does exist.